# Tailwind classes in content svg element not applied when used via url()

Tags: html, css, svg, tailwind-css

The tailwind classes are ignored when I try to load the svg via `before:content-gear` which is using url(). How can make it work?

tailwind config:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/index.html", "./icons/*.svg"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'bento-main': '#ff7a90',
        'bento-bg': '#2d394d',
        'bento-sub': '#4a768d',
        'bento-sub-alt': '#263041',
        'bento-text': '#fffaf8',

      },
      content: {
        'gear': 'url("/icons/gear.svg")',
      }

    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

index html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="/dist/output.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="bg-bento-bg box-border ">
      <div class="bg-bento-sub-alt rounded absolute  top-2/4 left-2/4 -translate-y-2/4 -translate-x-2/4">
        <h1 class=" font-semibold text-bento-sub py-3 pl-4 pr-2
        before:content-gear">
          Process <span class="text-bento-main">Mining</span>
        </h1>
      </div>
</body>
</html>`
```

gear.svg

```
        <svg       
        class="h-6 w-6 text-indigo-500 !important"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" >
          <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M9.594 3.94c.09-.542.56-.94 1.11-.94h2.593c.55 0 1.02.398 1.11.94l.213 1.281c.063.374.313.686.645.87.074.04.147.083.22.127.324.196.72.257 1.075.124l1.217-.456a1.125 1.125 0 011.37.49l1.296 2.247a1.125 1.125 0 01-.26 1.431l-1.003.827c-.293.24-.438.613-.431.992a6.759 6.759 0 010 .255c-.007.378.138.75.43.99l1.005.828c.424.35.534.954.26 1.43l-1.298 2.247a1.125 1.125 0 01-1.369.491l-1.217-.456c-.355-.133-.75-.072-1.076.124a6.57 6.57 0 01-.22.128c-.331.183-.581.495-.644.869l-.213 1.28c-.09.543-.56.941-1.11.941h-2.594c-.55 0-1.02-.398-1.11-.94l-.213-1.281c-.062-.374-.312-.686-.644-.87a6.52 6.52 0 01-.22-.127c-.325-.196-.72-.257-1.076-.124l-1.217.456a1.125 1.125 0 01-1.369-.49l-1.297-2.247a1.125 1.125 0 01.26-1.431l1.004-.827c.292-.24.437-.613.43-.992a6.932 6.932 0 010-.255c.007-.378-.138-.75-.43-.99l-1.004-.828a1.125 1.125 0 01-.26-1.43l1.297-2.247a1.125 1.125 0 011.37-.491l1.216.456c.356.133.751.072 1.076-.124.072-.044.146-.087.22-.128.332-.183.582-.495.644-.869l.214-1.281z" />
          <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M15 12a3 3 0 11-6 0 3 3 0 016 0z" />
        </svg>
```

I copy pasted the svg element into the index.html body to test if it works without loading the svg file via url() and it does. I added the .svg to the tailwind config to make sure it creates output for it, but I don't see anything except the url(..) in the out directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really do that since the classes you are putting in the svg has nothing to do with the document you are in. Unless you declare it in the same html. Just like you pointed out, you are loading a resource from a different place the classes will never interact this way.

Here is a way to do:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/rGjdDPKfnG